# How to return diagonal of matrix as array in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, memory-management

Newbie in C and struggling with memory alocation. When I try to do something, usually I will get segmentation fault (core dumped). This time, my problem is with returning array of values on diagonal of squared matrix.

Here is code which I use and fail to return array:

```
float* return_diagonal (float** matrix, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(i == j) {
                arr_len++;
            }
        }
    }
    int k = 0;
    float *ret_arr = malloc(arr_len * sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(i == j) {
                arr_len[k] = matrix[i][j];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is code in main:

```
float* ret_arr = malloc(arr_len * sizeof(float));

ret_arr = return_diagonal(matrix, n);
printf("Diagonal:\n ");
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%f", ret_arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You're not returning from your function. It also seems you might not understand what `malloc` returns?

Comment: Yes, this is right. But also, I don't understand how malloc works at all. Missed to return, usually it would scream that there is no return statement, but not in VSC for some reason

Comment: The diagonal will always have n elements so the first pair of fors are unnecessary. Also, for the diagonal you could just use one for and take matrix[i][i].

Comment: `arr_len[k]` is most certanly an error your compiler should at least warn you about it if it doesn't please turn up the warnings.

Comment: "but not in VSC for some reason". VSC is an editor with some plugins, not a compiler. Whatever compiler you are using, turn up warning level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating a very simple thing. Nested loops and `if`s are not needed

```
float *return_diagonal (float** matrix, size_t n) 
{
    float *ret_arr = malloc(n * sizeof(*ret_arr));
    if(ret_arr)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            ret_arr[i] = matrix[i][i];    
    }
    return ret_arr;
}
```